# Create links in a PDF DOCUMENT that opens in a new browser tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, hyperlink

I have generated pdf in Ruby On Rails by converting the View directly to pdf format.

I tried inclued the following link:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.co.in/">Google</a>
```

and also the following:

```
<%= link_to "Google", "https://www.google.co.in/", target: "_blank" %>
```

But the problem is that even if I've included `target="_blank"` the link still opens in the same tab.
Is there any other attribute that does the trick?

Comment: I don't think this will work, because PDF is rendered by a plugin (or standalone PDF reader) and is probably unaware of it's environment.

Comment: I found this thread on Adobe forum: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/509409

Comment: They somehow solved the problem in the above thread. But its about Adobe InDesign..

Comment: True, so it's only possible to manually adapt the links in an Adobe programm.

Comment: target: "_blank" will only work if the PDF is viewed within a web browser, which has a PDF viewing helper which understands that link. You may try it out using Acrobat/Reader with the browser plug-in. It will no work if you view the PDF within a standalone PDF viewer (but it may open a web browser window).

Answer (score 2):

Try with rails `link_to`

**UPDATE**

```
<%= link_to "Google", "https://www.google.co.in/", target: "_blank" %>
```

Comment: should I put the "url" in quotes?

Comment: Yes, double quotes are require